# Not able to create wcf service object/client for reference in xamarin android

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

i want to access a wcf service so i added it as a web reference in my xamarin android project but whenever i try to create its client it does not recognize it. 
i am attaching screenshots in a step by step order

[This is the working wcf service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJvIc.png)

[I added it as a web refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdBGL.png)

[whenever i try to create its object it shows an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha0hZ.png)

[When i right click on the web reference and select view in object browser it shows nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFmr.png)

I tried rebuilding my solution, disabling windows firewall..
The service is hosted on other computer. Shall i host this service on my system and then try again? or is there any other fix? i am in desperate help!!

Comment: Still hasn't fixed

Answer (score 0):

> I tried rebuilding my solution, disabling windows firewall.. The service is hosted on other computer. Shall i host this service on my system and then try again? or is there any other fix? i am in desperate help!!

The added web reference functions as namespace, you need to access the specific class under this namespace, for example,If I have a `HelloWorld` class under this wcf service like:

```
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string SayHelloTo(string name)
    {
        return "Hello World to you, {name}";
    }
 }
```

You can use it using below codes after you add it as web reference:

```
WebReference1.HelloWorldService service=new WebReference1.HelloWorldService();
service.SayHelloTo("name");
```

Comment: i didn't get it, i added the wcf reference and there are no configuration options in the add service reference dialog box, there is only an option to change the default namespace.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using connected service. I renewed my answer, please have a check.

Comment: This is where i am getting the error, in the line "WebReference1.HelloWorldService", xamarin is not recognizing the "Webreference1" as an object of my wcf service and that's why i am not able to access the operations in the service for e.g here ".HelloWorldService"

Answer (score 0):

Ap per you original question "whenever I try to create its client it does not recognize it", In third screenshot I have found that assembly reference is missing to WebReference1. Try adding reference to your namespace assembly

```
using UIDummy.WebReference1;
```

Now create its client and see whether it recognizes or not.

Comment: i tried adding the reference like this but still it shows an error

Comment: you cannot call your methods by directly using webService reference you have to create WebReference1.YourServiceClient. These are basics of creating WCF services. Learn basics first, you can start from watching some online tutorials.

Comment: I have created some wcf services and consumed them as well, so it takes us to the point that i know how wcf services work. This service that i am trying to consume is not created by me i am just consuming this service but i dont know what is causing an error for the object creation of the service